# No preview of custom UIStackView in Storyboard despite using IBDesignable

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistackview, ibdesignable

I don't know what's causing the problem but I can't see the preview of my custom element in .storyboard file. When I run it on the device it is here and works fine (looks the same as my .xib file), but in the Storyboard it's just a blank space.

[image]

Moreover there are two erros. I've searched all over the internet but couldn't make them disappear.

[image]

My code:

ReusableStackView.swift:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ReusableStackView: UIStackView {

    @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackLabel: UITextField!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        stackViewSetUp()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        stackViewSetUp()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        stackViewSetUp()
        stackView.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }

    func stackViewSetUp(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ReusableView", owner: self, options: nil)
        stackView.frame = self.bounds
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        addSubview(stackView)

    }
}
```

My ViewController does not have any logic connected to the ReusableStackView.

Comment: I've tried cleaning the project and other things. Weird thing is that now I don't have this warning and it still works fine when I run it on the device but there is no preview. I've tried UIView with the same code and it appeard in StoryBoard.

Comment: This is a known issue, happened to me as well. A clean sometimes helps, but it's generally permanent. File a radar.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:
Instead of `addSubview(stackView)` add add `addArrangedSubview(stackView)`. Now the preview appears in the IB.